# Chaining link_to content_tag Image_tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, content-tag

I have the following code:

```
<%= link_to(content_tag(image_tag('img_blank.png', alt: "Continue"),:div, [class: "btn", id: "continue"])) %>
```

however, I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `each_pair' for [{:class=>"btn", :id=>"continue"}]:Array
```

Is it possible to chain erb tags like this?  What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post, in HTML, what you *want* that code to look like?

Comment: <div id='continue' class='btn'

Comment: <a href='#'>
  <div id='continue' class='btn'>
    <img src='img_blank.png' alt="Continue"></img>
  </div>
</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write the code for easier reading:

```
<%= link_to("/url") do %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, class: "btn", id: "continue") do %>
    <%= image_tag('img_blank.png', alt: "Continue") %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Output:

```
<a href="/url">
  <div class="btn" id="continue">
    <img alt="Continue" src="/images/img_blank.png">
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Nice!  Your second edit was right on target.  For those who follow, can you ID what was wrong?

Comment: For the code working, in your question, just remove square brackets.